# Excess colomns in the query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a simple interface for a list of companies using MySQL and PHP.  So, I want to fetch some information from my database.

Here are my tables:

- **companies_data** - only for system information.
- **corporate_data** - here I want to keep information about big companies.
- **individual_data** - and here I want to keep information about little companies.

So, here is the tables
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Iy39mfe.png]

And here is the query that I've written:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.user_id,
    a.added,
    a.`status`,
    a.company_id,
    a.company_type,
    a.deposit,
    a.individual_operations_cache,
    a.corporate_operations_cache,
    a.physical_operations_cache,
    b.full_name,
    b.tax_number,
    b.address,
    b.statement_date,
    b.psrn,
    c.full_name,
    c.tax_number,
    c.address,
    c.statement_date,
    c.psrn
FROM
    companies_data a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN corporate_data b
        ON (a.company_id = b.id) AND a.company_type = 0 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN individual_data c
        ON (a.company_id = c.id) AND a.company_type = 1
WHERE
    a.user_id = 3
```

This is just the code for a test, I'll expand it soon.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6ptdnsj.png]

As you see, I've got result with extra fields like %field_name%1, %another_field_name%1 and so on. Of course it is not the mysql error - what I've asked that I've got - but I want to remove this fields? It's possible or I must convert this output on the application side?

Comment: You should use a union rather then the second join. Even better merge your tables `corporate_data` and `individual_data` into one table.

Comment: MySQL doesn't do that by itself, nor do any of the PHP extensions for MySQL. You must be using a PHP data access library that adds the extra fields so that associative array keys (or object fields) don't overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thos %field_name%1, %another_field_name%1 , are visible since you are selecting them in your query:
            b.full_name,
            b.tax_number,
            b.address,
            b.statement_date,
            b.psrn,
            c.full_name,
            c.tax_number,
            c.address,
            c.statement_date,
            c.psrn

When you use fields with the same name in distinct tables, then the result column name come with this identifier field1, field2, fieldn... in order to distinguish from which table does the field come from.
If you want to avoid this names, you can use aliases as follows:
           [...]
            b.full_name as corporate_full_name,
           [...]

Probably, if every common fields are coincident, you won´t need to show them all, so just remove them from the select.

Hope being usefull for you.
Br.

Comment: But I want to do something like this, because creating extra fields will be difficult to edit later. 
![Pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/diw3lhk07ecsx05/pic.png)

Comment: Well, I've created another query. (table_1 join table_2) union (table_1 join table_3) and it works perfectly. Thanks all!